# Question about using a Cut Capo

Tags: guitar, capos

I am considering getting one. I like to know the way the cut capo is used on electric or acoustic guitar.

What are some tunings that are used? Can I use a combination of capos?

Comment: I edited your question a bit, because it was primarily opinion based

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use a cut capo on the second fret to push down the A, d, and g strings. I've seen it being used in standard tuning. So you get the notes (from low to high):

> E B e a b e'

which is an Esus4 chord.
Of course you can come up with new creative ways to use a cut capo, but as far as I know they are most commonly used with standard tuning to play songs in E major.

Answer (score 1):

The two kinds of cut capo that I would find useful are the DADGAD capo that mimics the DADGAD tuning (Just like Matt L. said above). I find that capo extremely useful because DADGAD tuning sounds good, but when you use a capo you don't have to re-learn the chords. You can also achieve the same effect by using a standard capo backwards Like in this picture https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQWbFR8voGkgDHNMxdnCkrSO7SYiNGxBd4HSG_22gYFi0oH8M_

The other kind of cut capo that I think would be useful is a drop D capo. This is nice for the same reasons as I said above. You can mimic a drop D capo by capo-ing upside down like in this picture https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Bx9Q9U9matc/hqdefault.jpg

I'm sure that there are many other kinds of useful cut capos, but those are the two that I know of. Both the drop D and DADGAD capos can be used upside down. One of my favorite capo setups that I have ever used is an upside down drop D capo on fret 5, then play in G. 
You could also get a spider capo, which lets you mimic any kind of cut capo you could want.